# spark graphx multiple edge types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have started using spark very recently. Currently I am testing on a bipartite graph that has different vertex and edge types.

From the research I did in graphx, to have different edges and some with properties I need to subclass the edges.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
scala> trait VertexProperty
defined trait VertexProperty

scala> case class paperProperty(val paperid: Long, val papername: String, val doi: String, val keywords: String) extends VertexProperty
defined class paperProperty

scala> case class authorProperty(val authorid: Long, val authorname: String) extends VertexProperty
defined class authorProperty

scala> val docsVertces: RDD[(VertexId, VertexProperty)] = docs.rdd.map(x => (x(0).asInstanceOf[VertexId],paperProperty(x(0).asInstanceOf[VertexId],x(1).asInstanceOf[String],x(2).asInstanceOf[String],x(3).asInstanceOf[String])))
docsVertces: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, VertexProperty)] = MapPartitionsRDD[23] at map at <console>:47

scala> val authorVertces: RDD[(VertexId, VertexProperty)] = authors.rdd.map(x => (x(0).asInstanceOf[VertexId],authorProperty(x(0).asInstanceOf[Long],x(1).asInstanceOf[String])))
authorVertces: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, VertexProperty)] = MapPartitionsRDD[24] at map at <console>:41

scala> val vertices = VertexRDD(docsVertces ++ authorVertces)
vertices: org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexRDD[VertexProperty] = VertexRDDImpl[28] at RDD at VertexRDD.scala:57

scala>
```

However I failing with the edges.

```
scala> class EdgeProperty()
defined class EdgeProperty

scala> case class authorEdgeProperty( val doccount: Long) extends  EdgeProperty()
defined class authorEdgeProperty

scala> case class citeEdgeProperty() extends  EdgeProperty()
defined class citeEdgeProperty

scala> // edge using subclass will not work we need to have one consistent superclass

scala> val docauthoredges = docauthor.map(x => Edge(x(0).asInstanceOf[VertexId],x(1).asInstanceOf[VertexId],     authorEdgeProperty(x(1).asInstanceOf[Long])))
docauthoredges: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[authorEdgeProperty]] = [srcId: bigint, dstId: bigint ... 1 more field]

scala> val docciteedges = doccites.map(x => Edge(x(0).asInstanceOf[VertexId],x(1).asInstanceOf[VertexId], citeEdgeProperty()))
docciteedges: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[citeEdgeProperty]] = [srcId: bigint, dstId: bigint ... 1 more field]

scala> docauthoredges.unionAll(docciteedges)
<console>:52: error: type mismatch;
 found   :    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[citeEdgeProperty]]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[authorEdgeProperty]]
       docauthoredges.unionAll(docciteedges)
                               ^

scala>
```

I attempted to cast the edge to their superclass and am recieving the following message:

```
scala> val docauthoredges = docauthor.map(x => Edge(x(0).asInstanceOf[VertexId],x(1).asInstanceOf[VertexId],         authorEdgeProperty(x(1).asInstanceOf[Long]).asInstanceOf[EdgeProperty]))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for EdgeProperty
- field (class: "EdgeProperty", name: "attr")
- root class: "org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge"
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:598)
...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit futile because GraphX doesn't support `Datasets` and both edges and vertices should be passed as `RDDs`, but for the sake of argument:

- You get the first exception because distributed data structures in Spark are invariant. Don't use `asInstanceOf`. Just be explicit with type annotations.
- You get the second exception because `Datasets` are further limited by the usage of `Encoders`. All object in the `Dataset` have to use the same `Encoder` what in this case is possible only with binary encoder which won't implicitly accessible for user defined class.

With these two pieces combined:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoders}

sealed trait EdgeProperty

case class AuthorEdgeProperty(val doccount: Long) extends  EdgeProperty
case class CiteEdgeProperty() extends EdgeProperty

val docauthoredges: Dataset[EdgeProperty] = spark.range(10)
  .map(AuthorEdgeProperty(_): EdgeProperty)(Encoders.kryo[EdgeProperty])

val docciteedges: Dataset[EdgeProperty] = spark.range(5)
  .map(_ => CiteEdgeProperty(): EdgeProperty)(Encoders.kryo[EdgeProperty])

val edges: Dataset[EdgeProperty] = docauthoredges.union(docciteedges)
```

Convert to `RDD` to make it usable in GraphX:

```
edges.rdd
```